# Why my table takes more spaces even it have less row then other table?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have the following table

```
Create table my_source(
   ID number(15) not null,
   Col_1 Varchar 2(3000),
   Col_2 Varchar 2(3000),
   Col_3 Varchar 2(3000),
   Col_4 Varchar 2(3000),
   Col_5 Varchar 2(3000),
   ...
   Col_90 Varchar 2(3000)
);
```

This table have 6,926,220 rows.

Now I am going to create two table based on this table.

Target1

```
Create table el_temp as
select 
    id,
    Col_1,
    Col_2,
    Col_3,
    Col_4,
    Col_5,
    Col_6,
    Col_7,
    Col_8,
    Col_9,
    Col_10,
    Col_11,
    Col_12
from
    my_source;
```

Target2:

```
Create table el_temp2 as
select DISTINCT
    id,
    Col_1,
    Col_2,
    Col_3,
    Col_4,
    Col_5,
    Col_6,
    Col_7,
    Col_8,
    Col_9,
    Col_10,
    Col_11,
    Col_12
from
    my_source;

select count(*) from el_temp; -- 6926220
select count(*) from el_temp2; --6880832
```

The only difference between el_temp and el_temp2 is the "distinct" operator.
Now I got the following result from SQL Developer

[image]

It is a surprise result to me that EL_TEMP, the one with more rows have a smaller size, while the el_temp2 have less row but a bigger size.

Could anyone share me any reason and how to avoid this happen?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post example data from `my_source`. I'm curious how your `ID` column is set-up.

Comment: Did you gather statistics on those tables? If not, do so and then compare the result.

Comment: Also, is `my_source.ID` configured as a PK column or not? Why are all your columns `NULL`able?

Comment: @Dai The ID is just setup as a normal ID. It is not a primary key, as it allows multiple lines for the same ID. But true that the ID column is not null.

Comment: @Littlefoot, how to gather statistics on those tables in SQL Developer? Could you please share me more detail? Thanks!

Comment: For example: `EXEC DBMS_STATS.gather_table_stats('SCHEMA_NAME', 'EL_TEMP');` (replace SCHEMA_NAME with its actual name).

Comment: What query did you use to get the results you show in sqldev? As @Littlefoot said, gather stats and compare the blocks column for the 2 tables in user_tables.

Comment: @gsalem, I just use the DBA function:

View > DBA> (Database Connection) > Storage > Tablespaces> (Space name) > Objects

Comment: @Littlefoot, I tried to use EXEC DBMS_STATS.gather_table_stats('SCHEMA_NAME', 'EL_TEMP'); but I didn't turn up with any result.

Comment: gather_table_stats does not return anything. you have to check the 'blocks' column in user_tables. The method you used gives you the space allocated, not what is actually used there.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause is that the table has undergone some updates to existing rows over its lifetime.

By default, when you create a table, we reserve 10% of the space in each block for rows to grow (due to updates).  As updates occur, that space is used up, so your blocks might be (on average) around 95% full.

When you do "create table as select" from that table to another, we will take those blocks and pad them out again to 10% free space, thus making it slightly larger.

If PCTFREE etc is unfamiliar to you, I've also got a tutorial video to get you started here

https://youtu.be/aOZMp5mncqA